# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: mysql, sql

Amigos Tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy haciendo un insert sencillo, y me da este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' fecsus, fecpub, idubiccn, motivo, dia, mes ) Values (3132,'10-06-20' at line 3 in /var/www/html/web/adminutf/suspe/altasus.php:107

Los Datos son estos:

```
[identrena] => 3132
        [fechas] => 2020-06-10
        [fechap] => 2020-04-11
        [dia] => 1
        [mes] => 2
       [hipo] => LP
       [idsusp] => 1



    $stmt="INSERT INTO turf_entrenasus

            SET identrena, fecsus, fecpub, idubiccn,         motivo, dia, mes )

            Values 
                (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

    $InsertarPoscn = $conn->prepare($stmt); // Se crea     un objeto PDOStatement.  

        $InsertarPoscn->bindParam(1, $IdEntre,  PDO::PARAM_INT); // Se asigna una variable para la consulta.
        $InsertarPoscn->bindParam(2, $fechasus, PDO::PARAM_STR); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
        $InsertarPoscn->bindParam(3, $fechapub, PDO::PARAM_STR); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
        $InsertarPoscn->bindParam(4, $IdHipo,     PDO::PARAM_INT); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
        $InsertarPoscn->bindParam(5, $IdSusp,   PDO::PARAM_INT); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
    $InsertarPoscn->bindParam(6, $Dia,      PDO::PARAM_INT); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
    $InsertarPoscn->bindParam(7, $Mes,      PDO::PARAM_INT ); // Se asigna una variable para la consulta.


        $InsertarPoscn->execute(); // Se ejecuta la consulta.

     $ultimo_id_insertado = $conn->lastInsertId();

    if ($ultimo_id_insertado == 0)
    {
        echo " <br>El Registro NO a sido dado de ALTA";
    }   else
    {
        echo "<br>El Registro a sido dado de alta con    exito";
    }
```

El error lo da al ejecutar y hace varias horas que le estoy dando vueltas y no lo puedo encontrar, para que lo vean bien los valores son todos números enteros  salvo las 2 fechas y acá se los muestro en el orden que están:
3132 - 2020-06-10 - 2020-04-11 - 3 - 1 - 1 - 2

Comment: Esos espacios se pusieron acá, estan normales

Comment: SET identrena, fecsus, fecpub, idubiccn, motivo, dia, mes )

Comment: Trata con la sintaxis siguiente: `INSERT INTO tutabla(columna1, columna2....columnaN) VALUES (.....................)`

Comment: Gracias a su pregunta, me di cuenta que faltaba un parentesis, lo puse y sigue dando error ( identrena, fecsus, fecpub, idubiccn, motivo, dia, mes )

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, ese era el problema. hace horas que me estaba volviendo loco, MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis mas común (pero no por eso la única):

```
INSERT INTO tuTabla(columna1, columna2)
VALUES
("valor1", "valor2");
```

Sin embargo revisando la sintaxis en la documentación de [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) me parece que lo que tratas de hacer debería tener esta sintaxis:

```
 INSERT INTO tuTabla SET columna1 = "valor1",  columna2 = "valor2";
```

Entonces pudieras probar del modo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO turf_entrenasus
    SET identrena = ?,
        fecsus = ?,
        fecpub = ?,
        idubiccn = ?,
        motivo = ?,
        dia = ?,
        mes = ?;
```

Aunque esto último no lo he probado aún

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar

Comment: Estimado,Betam, hice la prueba y funcionó , lo hice así:

Comment: $stmt="INSERT INTO turf_entrenasus SET  identrena=?, fecsus=?, fecpub=?, idubiccn=?, motivo=?, dia=?, mes=? ";

$InsertarPoscn = $conn->prepare($stmt); // Se crea un objeto PDOStatement.

Comment: Nuevamente, Muchas Gracias